# Excel VBA find specific date

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

in Excel 2003, I have a list of sorted dates and I want to find the last one before a specific date. The specific date might not be listed. For example the last date before 01/08/2015 but the nearest date listed might be in 20016.
The dates listed in my report vary each week.

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried anything as yet, I've not found anything that looks like it'll work also I'm quite new to this so not advanced enough to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some VBA that will tell you the last date before a date that you specify:

```
Public Function getLastDate() As String
    Const columnNo As Byte = 1
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Integer, r As Integer
    Dim inputDate As String, searchDate As Date, latestDate As Date

    ' get date to search for
    inputDate = InputBox("Enter date value", "Date", Date)

    ' validate date entered
    If (inputDate = vbNullString) Then Exit Function
    On Error Resume Next
    searchDate = CDate(inputDate)
    If (Err.Number > 0) Then Exit Function
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnNo).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 2 To lastRow
        ' check cell isn't empty
        If (ws.Cells(r, columnNo) = vbNullString) Then Exit For

        ' check that the cell date is before the input date
        If (DateValue(ws.Cells(r, columnNo)) > searchDate) Then Exit For

        ' remember the last date checked in case its the one I want
        latestDate = DateValue(ws.Cells(r, columnNo))
    Next r

    ' return date value
    If (latestDate = 0) Then
        getLastDate = "No date found"
    Else
        getLastDate = latestDate
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks I shall give this a go.

Comment: @Paulx22 if this is what you were looking for, you should accept it as the answer (checkmark on the left side)

Answer (score 0):

You said that your list of dates is sorted. Then you won't need VBA, but can use the simple formula below. Here I am assuming that you sorted your list **ascendingly**.

```
=OFFSET($A$2,COUNTIF($A:$A,"<" & $D$4)-1,0,1,1)
```

The Dates are in column A, starting in Row 2. The specified date is in D4.

Screenshot:

[image]

If your list is sorted **descendingly**, the formula would be:

```
=OFFSET($A$2,COUNTIF($A:$A,">=" & $D$4),0,1,1)
```

Comment: Handy to know if used in isolation, I'll make a note, but this is part of a series of actions. With more to follow.